# Schemathesis issues with stateful testing using OpenAPI links

Tags: django-rest-framework, pytest, openapi, django-testing, schemathesis

We are using schemathesis for testing our API’s, we want to utilize it for stateful testing, hence we defined the links in our OpenAPI as follows:

Endpoint which will use link:

```
{"post":
     {
       "operationId":
       "createProfile","description":"",
       "parameters":[],
      "requestBody":{
         "content":{
            "application/json":{
               "schema":{
                  "$ref":"#/components/schemas/Profile"
               }
            },
            "application/x-www-form-urlencoded":{
               "schema":{
                  "$ref":"#/components/schemas/Profile "
               }
            },
            "multipart/form-data":{
               "schema":{
                  "$ref":"#/components/schemas/Profile"
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "responses":{
         "201":{
            "content":{
               "application/json":{
                  "schema":{
                     "$ref":"#/components/schemas/Profile"
                  }
               }
            },
            "links":{
               "GetProfileById":{
                  "operationId":"retrieveProfile",
                  "parameters":{
                     "id":"$response.body#/id"
                  },
                  "description":"The`id`value returned in the response can be used as the`id`parameter in`GET /profile/{id}`.\\n"
               }
            },
            "description":""
         }
      },
      "tags":[
         "profile"
      ]

}
}
```

The linked endpoint:

```
{
   "/profile/{id}":{
      "get":{
         "operationId":"retrieveProfile",
         "description":"",
         "parameters":[
            {
               "name":"id",
               "in":"path",
               "required":true,
               "description":"A unique integer value identifying this Profile.",
               "schema":{
                  "type":"string"
               }
            }
         ],
         "responses":{
            "200":{
               "content":{
                  "application/json":{
                     "schema":{
                        "$ref":"#/components/schemas/Profile"
                     }
                  }
               },
               "description":""
            }
         },
         "tags":[
            "profile"
         ]
      },
      "components":{
         "schemas":{
            "Profile":{
               "type":"object",
               "properties":{
                  "id":{
                     "type":"integer",
                     "readOnly":true
                  },
                  "name":{
                     "type":"string",
                     "maxLength":100
                  },
                  "afkorting":{
                     "type":"string",
                     "maxLength":10
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I have followed the example from:

https://schemathesis.readthedocs.io/en/stable/stateful.html#how-to-specify-connections
and
https://swagger.io/docs/specification/links/

I call it in following way:

```
headers = {
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
'Authorization': f'Basic {base64_encoded_auth_header}'
}

schema = schemathesis.from_uri(f"{base_url}/api-schema", headers=headers)

APIWorkflow = schema.as_state_machine()
TestAPI = APIWorkflow.TestCase

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def authorization_header():
return headers

@schema.parametrize(endpoint="/profile")
@settings(max_examples=1)
def test_api_post(case, authorization_header):
case.headers = authorization_header
response = case.call()
case.validate_response(response)
```

AND

```
following way:

    @pytest.fixture(scope="session")
    def rest_schema():
        return schema

@pytest.fixture
def state_machine(rest_schema, authorization_header):
class APIWorkflow(rest_schema.as_state_machine()):
def before_call(self, case):
case.headers = {}
case.headers = authorization_header

        def validate_response(self, response, case):
            case.validate_response(response)
    
    return APIWorkflow

def test_statefully(state_machine):
state_machine.run(
settings=settings(
max_examples=1,
deadline=None,
stateful_step_count=1,
)
)
```

I have also looked up the discussion regarding stateful testing here,
#`https://github.com/schemathesis/schemathesis/discussions/1212`

What I expected:
I expected schemathesis to do the POST /profile operation and pick the #id attribute from response and fill that in for /profile/{id} GET rest call.

What I got:
Now the problem it does not pick the link from POST method, it just tries to call it individually. It just ignores the response from /profile POST operation and performs the GET /profile/{id} operation using a random value for {id}.

My questions:

What am I missing here to link the GET profile/{id} endpoint to connect with the POST /profile operation?
After fixing 1): Could we also use these links for automated testing of DELETE operations, where the DELETE operation would be /profile/{id} ? 
Environment information:
Python version: 3.9 
Operating System: Mac OS Monterey 12.0.1 
Django version: 4.1.1 
Rest framework version: 3.14.0 
Schemathesis version: 3.23.0 \